# Wildcard search in the node selector with HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

this is the part of my code

```
<div>
<div style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px"> blah </div>
<div style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px"> blah </div>
<div>
```

how can I select 2nd and 3rd divs into 'node.SelectNodes' ?

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@style='PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px']");
```

Can I do some sort of wilcard search for 2px and 4px or any other px?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `contains()` to do a string-in-string match.

```
node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@style, 'PADDING-BOTTOM:')]");
```